# How do i work out if 2 lists are sharing any numbers in the same position in python?

Tags: python, list, compare

I have written a mastermind game in python that generates a random 4 digit number and compares it with a user input. I want my program to print out how many numbers the user has inputted which are shared with what the program has generated and how many of those numbers are in the same place. My attempt is below; however, my way of calculating this doesn't work can you please point out what i could do to fix this thanks.

```
from random import *
numbers = [randint(1, 9) for _ in range(4)]
guess = 0
guesses = []
num_right_numbers = 0
pos = 0

while numbers != guesses:
    # Ask user to guess the value
    guess = int(input("Guess the 4 digit number "))
    if guess > 999 and guess < 10000:
        guesses = [int(x) for x in str(guess)]
    else:
        print("You did not enter a 4 digit number")
        continue
    for val in guesses:
        if val in numbers:
            num_right_numbers += 1
            if numbers.index(val) == guesses.index(val):
                pos += 1
    print('You got ' + str(num_right_numbers) + ' numbers right.')
    print('You have ' + str(pos) + ' digits in the right place.')
    num_right_numbers = 0
    pos = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
"doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 1):

`.index()` will only return the first index where the number has been found in the list it is being applied to. The `enumerate` function is helpful for this problem, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
from random import *

numbers = [randint(1, 9) for _ in range(4)]
guess = 0
guesses = []
num_right_numbers = 0
pos = 0

print(numbers)

while numbers != guesses:
    # Ask user to guess the value
    guess = input("Guess the 4 digit number: ")

    # The if statement can be improved
    if len(guess) == 4 and guess.isdigit():
        guesses = [int(x) for x in guess]
    else:
        print("You did not enter a 4 digit number!")
        continue

    # Use enumerate to iterate through both indices and values
    for index, val in enumerate(guesses):
        if val in numbers:
            num_right_numbers += 1
            if numbers[index] == guesses[index]:
                pos += 1

    # 1 digit vs n digits
    if num_right_numbers == 1:
        print("You got " + str(num_right_numbers) + " number right.")
    else:
        print("You got " + str(num_right_numbers) + " numbers right.")

    # 1 digit vs n digits
    if pos == 1:
        print("You have " + str(pos) + " digit in the right place.")
    else:
        print("You have " + str(pos) + " digits in the right place.")

    num_right_numbers = 0
    pos = 0

print("You win!")
```

---

General answer to the problem mentioned in the title of the question, in case someone comes here looking only for this:

```
a = [1, 5, 4, 8, 3, 9, 0]
b = [3, 5, 9, 1, 2, 9, 4]

shared = [x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)]

print(shared)
```

Output:

```
[False, True, False, False, False, True, False]
```

To obtain the number of matches:

```
matches = sum(shared)

print(matches)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty in both respects.  First of all, the quantity exactly right (digit and position) has to be determined; the **index** operation returns only the *first* match.  Your current logic will give four hits for a guess of **2244** on the number **1234**, since the **in** operator will return **True** for each inquiry.

Start with:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if guess[i] == numbers[i]:
```

Now, you need to *disable* those from being used in any of the lesser matches (right digit, wrong position).

See how that works?  I won't do it for you -- SO is not a design or coding service -- but I think this should move you toward redesigning your solution.

Answer (score -1):

For two lists called a and b,

```
sum(a_elt == b_elt for a_elt, b_elt in zip(a,b))
```

tells you how many elements are in a and b with the same index and same value.

Loops are not very Pythonic -- the above code is much easier to read, write, debug, etc. Look into "comprehensions" if you want to learn more.